# String Interpolation using Dictionary of Unknown Keys and Number of Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
item_list = [x for x in notion_position_block.collection.get_rows()]
item_dict = {x.title: len(x.get_property('potential_hires')) for x in item_list}
```

Which gets me what I want:  `{'Full Stack Engineer': 3, 'Social Media Manager': 2, 'Backend Software Engineer': 1}`

The dictionaries key/value + num of elements will never be the same

How can I get this into a string if keys + num of elements are consistently changing?

What I am ultimately trying to get is:

```
Full Stack Engineer 3 
Social Media Manager 2
Backend Software Engineer 1
```

Edit:

Is it possible to get the dictionary into a string with some version of

`''.format()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want is a string, not the dictionary, I'd skip right to:

```
for x in notion_position_block.collection.get_rows():
    print(x.title, len(x.get_property('potential_hires')))
```

If you do still want that dictionary, you can skip the list. You're creating a list, then looping over it to make the dictionary. It seems easier to just go right for the dictionary right away.

```
item_dict = {x.title: len(x.get_property('potential_hires')) for x in notion_position_block.collection.get_rows()}

for title, total in item_dict.items():
    print(title, total)
```

Edit for "Is it possible to get the dictionary into a string with some version of ''.format()":
I'd use str.join for that:

```
', '.join(f'{title}: {total}' for title, total in item_dict.items())
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I did not put that in the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in item_dict.keys():
  print(x,item_dict[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understand you right, but this is how you can change this dictionary representation to the string form and put in a list.

Then if you want to have exactly the same outcome as you provided, you just have to make a basic for loop to print out the elements from the list

```
item_dict = {'Full Stack Engineer': 3, 'Social Media Manager': 2, 'Backend Software Engineer': 1}

string_rep = [(keys, values) for keys, values in item_dict.items()]
print(string_rep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) method to iterate over the key/value pairs of your dictionary:

```py
>>> for key, value in item_dict.items():
...     print(key, value)
... 
Full Stack Engineer 3
Social Media Manager 2
Backend Software Engineer 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the: ‘ Full Stack Engineer 3 ’ it means 3 - dictionary number or how many this words involve in item_list?
If first:

for i in item_dict.keys():
print(i,item_dict[i])